# CKeditor not displaying in asp.net page with hidden div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I have an ASP.net page that initially loads with a hidden div section.  when the user clicks 'edit' that div is displayed and I need the ckeditor to be displayed in there.  however, it does not.  if I load the page with div visible=true then it works fine.  any ideas?

Comment: Improve your question putting some prints/code blocks to help in the analysis

Comment: ok, essentially, in the aspx I include the ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code I'm guessing you are using an `UpdatePanel`.  If so you need to call `CKEDITOR.replace` again because the DOM has been changed and the TextArea that should become the editor now exists.

So use the below line in the method that shows the `div`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showEditor", "CKEDITOR.replace('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "');", true);
```

Comment: ok, essentially, in the aspx I include the ckeditor

then within< div runat=server visible=false>
        Comments:        
        <asp:textbox ID='txtComments' runat='server' Rows='4' TextMode='MultiLine'  readonly='false' />
        <script>
          CKEDITOR.replace('txtComments');
         </script>
</div>

Comment: That would probably work, just make sure you use the correct ID

Comment: looks like I spoke a little too soon.  now it renders the control but on the server side txtComments.text is blank.  I'm not sure why.  I tried this
function xferEditor() {
        document.all["txtComments"].text= CKEDITOR.instances['txtComments'].getData();
        alert("here:"+document.all["txtComments"].text);
    } 
and it does alert on the client but on the server its still an empty string